# overrideProvider(token) not working in nestJS for Test.createTestingModule

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, node-modules, code-injection, nestjs

I'm having a problem with overriding a provider in a test context. I know I'm missing something blindingly obvious, but I've tried loads of permutations and none have worked, so I'm putting this out to the hive mind.

I have the following structure:

**shared.module.ts**

```
@Module({
    providers: [
        DatabaseProvider,
        ConfigService,
        CacheService
    ],
    exports: [
        DatabaseProvider,
        ConfigService
        CacheService
    ],
    imports: [HttpModule],
})
```

where DatabaseProvider is defined as:

```
const DatabaseProvider = {
    provide: "MongoConnection",
    inject: [ConfigService],
    useFactory: async (config: ConfigService): Promise < typeof mongoose | Object > => {
        return await mongoose.connect(config.getString("MONGO_URI"), { useNewUrlParser: true });
    }
};
```

**my.module.ts**

```
@Module({
    imports: [SharedModule, HttpModule],
    exports: [MyService],
    controllers: [MyController],
    providers: [MyService],
})
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        SharedModule,
        MyModule
    ],
    providers: [
        ...
    ],
    controllers: [
        ...
    ]
})
```

**my.service.ts**

```
export class MyService {
    constructor(
        @Inject("MongoConnection") private readonly dbConnection: Connection,
        private _cache: CacheService
    ) { }
...
}
```

**my.spec.ts**

```
let cacheService = {...};
this.db = {...};

const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
        imports: [SharedModule, MyModule, HttpModule]
    })
    .overrideProvider(CacheService)
    .useValue(cacheService)
    .overrideProvider("MongoConnection")
    .useValue(this.db)
    .compile();
```

My issue is that the CacheService appears to be being overridden (it's using redis-mock defined in cacheService, instead of the default redis implementation in CacheService), but the MongoConnection is not - it is still calling the original DatabaseProvider from shared.module.ts.

Can someone point out what I'm missing?

Comment: Are you really using `@Inject()` instead of `@InjectConnection()` to inject the connection?

Comment: Ah, you're not using `@nestjs/mongoose`, right? Does anyting speak against using this package? https://github.com/nestjs/mongoose